# App crashes with "Terminated due to memory issue" for SKAction(named:)

Tags: skaction

App crashes with "Terminated due to memory issue" when i call SKAction(named:)  when the action does not exist.

My app has a number of sprite kit scenes (.sks files) and sprite kit action files. when a sprite is pressed, I try to instantiate an SKAction for that object. If the action I am requesting does not exist, the app will crash instead of returning nil. It seems that the system is searching thru all of the actions and somehow not releasing memory. Has anyone experienced this problem? If the amount of sks is reduced, it seems to solve the problem, but I need all of the SKS's

```
func runAction(node:SKNode, actionName:String) {

    guard let action = SKAction(named: actionName) else {

        print("!!!!!!! action not found:  \(actionName)")

        return
    }
    print("found action")
    node.run(action)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The action isn't found so it's infinitely printing out "!!!!!!! action not found:  (actionName)" until there is no more memory left.

Add a count or something so there is a max number of tries, probably use the dispatch queue so you can add a delay, and of course verify the action you're trying to send exists.

Comment: if the call fails, it only prints the message once and exits the fun. there is no repeated call of SKAction(named:)

Comment: Oh I misread `node.run(action)` as calling the same function again. That's all it's giving? Memory issue, No other details?

Comment: yes. very unstable. the memory issue seems to occur in various places (google it). It seems that it searches its "db" for the action, but it seems like theres a memory leak or something.

Answer (score 0):

After installing iOS 11.0 beta on my iPad, this functionality became more stable. It still crashes if an action is not found, but seems to be more stable when the action is present.

As a workaround, I am using SKAction(named: from:) instead. First I get the url of the action sks file, and then try to retrieve the SKAction from that file. Because this is a directed call for the action, no memory issues are occurring.